# Can this for loop be reduced to one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python code:

```
arr = [['name1', 101], ['name2', 234], ['name3', 456]]
nametolookfor = input("Please enter the name: ")
data = 0
for value in arr:
    if value[0] == nametolookfor:
        otherdata = value[1]
```

I was wondering if the for loop and its contents could be brought down to one line.

I have tried using list comprehensions but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: `otherdata = dict(arr).get(nametolookfor)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter for array elements where the name matches, then select only the value, and from that retrieve the first:

```
>>> arr = [['name1', 101], ['name2', 234], ['name3', 456]]
>>> nametolookfor = 'name2'
>>> [v for (n, v) in arr if n == nametolookfor][0]
234
```

Since your list is a list of key/value pairs where the key is (by definition) unique, you can also make it into a dictionary and have a direct lookup instead:

```
>>> lookup = dict(arr)
>>> lookup[nametolookfor]
234
```

Of course, if your `arr` is static, you can just declare it as a dictionary from the start to save you from having to do the conversion:

```
>>> lookup = { 'name1': 101, 'name2': 234, 'name3': 456 }
>>> lookup[nametolookfor]
234
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be close to what you want. Using next avoids some boilerplate later to check if the value exists.

```
next(value[0] for value in are if value[0] == nametolookfor, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is posible in list comprehensions. Follow this

```
[value[1] for value in arr if value[0] == nametolookfor]
```

`Please enter the name:` name1

> Output:  [101]

Assume your list `arr = [['name1', 101], ['name2', 234], ['name3', 456], ['name1', 202], ['name1', 303]]` and set input `nametolookfor = name1` then result will be

```
[101, 202, 303]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
otherdata = dict(arr)[nametolookfor]
```

Since the list is a list of key/value pairs where the key is unique, you can convert it into a dictionary and have a direct lookup.